# How can I see the CSS for the most recent Android Facebook app?

Tags: android, css

How can I see the CSS for the most recent Android Facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Facebook app is written with native code. They ditched HTML 5.

Comment: Can you explain ? I don't know what that means!

Comment: @CharlieAllombert That means, the new Facebook app is return in Native Java Code, They have left the HTML5 App they used to have earlier